# Check whether MySQL Innodb Rows are compressed

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5

After setting the various variables to enable compression on the Innodb Barracuda tables, what query will you use to check that those tables are indeed compressed?

Comment: Have you taken a look at that chapter? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-compression-tuning-monitoring.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use the show command to see the table definition :**

```
mysql:>show create table <table name >
```

Comment: Nyxynyx, in addition to "setting variables", you'll also need to [specify compression when creating or altering a table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-compression-usage.html). Then when you use Up_One's solution you should see `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED` in the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @NathanJolly Thank you for the reminder, I left that out in the question.